# SLF4J: avoiding fully qualified class names

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

This will be easy for your guys!

How do I prevent SLF4J from displaying fully qualified class names (e.g. `com.mycompany.mypackage.MyObject`) and just output `MyObject`?

I generally prefer this:

1)

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(MyObject.class);
```

to this:

2)

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger("MyObject");
```

so that when I refactor/rename `MyObject` to `MyThing` the reference gets updated automatically for me.

Yet.. with 1) I get unwieldy output: `com.mycompany.mypackage.MyObject`

I just need to see `MyObject` in the log...

Optionally: if you know how to selectively colour output (e.g. `\e[0;33m` for example) based on log level, that would be great to know.

Comment: Do you use log4j as the underlying logger? Could you post your properties file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [API](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html) for the `SimpleLogger`, you could try setting the `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showShortLogName` property of your `LOGGER` instance to `true`.

From the API:

> `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showShortLogName` - Set to `true` if you want the
>   last component of the name to be included in output messages. Defaults
>   to `false`.

Comment: Awesome. That's what I needed. Accepted! I only know how to set this through the CLI (e.g. `java -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showShortLogName=true`), is there a way to do this either programmatically or via a config file? Could you add a very short example to your answer to make it complete for posterity, please?